# Espacio en blanco a la derecha en mis páginas de Wordpress

Tags: css3, wordpress-theme

necesito su ayuda. Estoy creando una página web para Wordpress. Estoy trabajando con un tema hijo. Pero mientras que estaba trabajando con el código, me agregó un espacio en blanco como en la siguiente imagen.

Ha cambiado y quitado mi código CSS a ver si es eso y sigue igual.

El error comenzó a aparecer luego de que comencé a cambiar el tamaño de las columnas en la tienda. Pero quiso esa porción del código y sigue igual también.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hola, saludos. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano. Aquí paso la página web: http://mind-paradise.com/